# Actualizar multiples registros con EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Resulta que tengo una tabla con 2 columnas:

```
Material|DescripcionMaterial
```

Se da el caso que la columna `Material` puede contener registro asi: (Es solo ejemplo)

```
Material+++++++DescripcionMaterial

1000           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1000           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1001           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Digamos que cuando yo quiero actualizar un registro unico uso lo siguiente:

```
//SE ACTUALIZA EL MATERIAL
        public void UpdateMaterial(int id, string material, string descripcion)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
                {
                    var entidad = ctx.Material.Where(x => x.id == id).SingleOrDefault();
                    entidad.material1 = material;
                    entidad.nombreMaterial = descripcion;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Como puedo hacer para actualizar los registros que contienen mas de una coincidencia (segun leyendo al usar `SingleOrDefault` me daria error si existe mas de un record al buscar), como haria entonces para actualizar cuando exista por ejemplo 1000 y este se repita?

Por ejemplo pasar lo siguiente a EF:

```
UPDATE Tabla SET Material='5555' WHERE Material='1000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
public void UpdateMaterial(int id, string material, string descripcion)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
                {
                    var entidad = ctx.Material.Where(x => x.{prop} == {prop}).toList();
                    foreach(var item in entidad){
                      item.material1 = material;
                      item.nombreMaterial = descripcion;
                    }
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Donde prop sería la condición. PV mae